# php insert to database row id and session id when click a button

Tags: php, mysql, button, insert

How do I insert to the database when you click a button? 
I also need to insert in the same command, the row [id] and SESSION [id] 
I use an html page that calls the php, then the variaves SESSION are not in my php page. I'm stuck here .. please help

```
   <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;   
} 

  ?>
  <?php
  $deets = $_POST['deets'];
  $deets = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $deets);

  include ("connect.php");

  $events = '';
  $query = mysql_query('SELECT hora, status FROM horario');
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($num_rows > 0) {
$events .= '<div id="eventsControl"><button class="btn2" style=" float:right;" onMouseDown="overlay()"><b>Fechar</b></button><p><b> ' . $deets . '</b></p></div> <br />';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $desc = $row['hora'];
    $desc1 = "<input type='submit' class='btn1' name='insert' value='Marcar Hora' />";
    $events .= '<div id="eventsBody">' . $desc . '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$desc1.  '<br /><hr><br /></div>';
}
}

echo $events;

if(isset($_REQUEST['insert']))
{
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO eventos (id, data, idhora,) VALUES ('', '.$deets.', '$row[id]', 'session[id]')";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 Problems I initially see, although I don't have full context of your code.

First,  I don't see you starting the session anywhere, this requires you to run session_start(); before you try to grab the session ID or save any variables into the session.

Second,  as far as I understand it you'll need to reference the session id by doing something like this.

$id = session_id();

Comment: ok thanks, got it $_SESSION['email'] to get user info..but i still need fit a button to insert data to db